# Rijndael initialization vector with 16 bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net, cryptography, rijndael

I have to credit card number to be encrypted and stored in database as a string. I do the following

```
RijndaelManaged rijMan = new RijndaelManaged();
byte[] encrypt = Encrypt(txtCredit.Text, rijMan.Key, rijMan.IV);
string card = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypt);
string key = Convert.ToBase64String(rijMan.Key);
string iv = Convert.ToBase64String(rijMan.IV);
```

and this is encrypt function:

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(string message, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
    byte[] encrypted;
    using (RijndaelManaged rijMan = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        rijMan.Key = key;
        rijMan.IV = iv;
        ICryptoTransform encrypt = rijMan.CreateEncryptor(rijMan.Key, rijMan.IV);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
                {
                    sw.Write(message);
                }
                encrypted = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    return encrypted;
}
```

And i store them all in database. This seems to be fine. But when i retrieve back the string from database and use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string)` to convert to `byte`, it throws an exception

> Specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm.

Is it possible to generate the IV such that it is 16 bytes ? Thanks in advance for the reply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the top of your post you are using BASE64 algorithm to convert IV bytes to string

```
string ivString = Convert.ToBase64String(rijMan.IV);
```

and then in the bottom of your post you are using UTF8 encoding to read string into byte array

```
byte[] iv = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ivString);
```

but you should use BASE64 algorithm again:

```
byte[] iv = Convert.FromBase64String(ivString);
```

BTW: I hope you are not storing AES key (rijMan.Key) in the same database as your encrypted credit card number because that would make whole encryption completely useless.

Comment: Storing the IV alongside the ciphertext is standard - it's not secret and needs to be different for each message.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Good point. I have edited my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: I generate new IV for every entry.
    RijndaelManaged rijMan = new RijndaelManaged();
    byte[] encrypt = Encrypt(txtCredit.Text, rijMan.Key, rijMan.IV);